# Shard 0's process exited before its Client became ready

Tags: javascript, discord.js, sharding

Im trying to make a bot that can count a members messages, and it was working just fine until it just gave up out of nowhere.

this is my sharding manager

```
    const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, ActivityType, PermissionsBitField, AuditLogEvent } = require('discord.js');
    const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');
    const { config } = require("dotenv");

    config();

    const manager = new ShardingManager('./yourBotScript.js', { 
      totalShards: 'auto',
      token: process.env.BOT_TOKEN
    });

    manager.on('shardCreate', shard => {
      console.log(`Shard ${shard.id} launched`);
    });

    manager.spawn();
```

heres the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NHbL2GWg

Ive tried experimenting with different types of answers ive found on the internet, especially around here, but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: how big is this bot? if it's just for your server, you don't need shards